# Heroku app calling external web service on a VPN

Tags: security, heroku, proxy, vpn

1. So, we have a Heroku app.
2. We have a web service running on an intranet.
3. That intranet needs a VPN connection for outsiders to
   connect.
4. We want our Heroku app to call the web service on the intranet, via
   VPN.

How would you tackle this?

*Some thoughts....*

Heroku doesn't seem to have a VPN client we can activate on our app :(

I'm aware some routers can handle the VPN gubbins for us. Is there an online service that let's us setup a VPN proxy to our intranet site?

Thanks in advance

T

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be possible I'm afraid, certainly at least not via VPN. Heroku uses Amazon EC2 so you can't even narrow it down to an IP range to permit access. Heroku is a closed system so you can't install additional components so unless it's something accessible via http/https then it's a no go.

Comment: That is not entirely true.  Heroku uses Linux under the covers but you don't have root access.  So anything you can do on Linux as a non-root user, you can do on Heroku.  You can connect out to any service using any TCP protocol.  But you can only listen for HTTP connections.  Unfortunately this rules out setting up VPNs and SSH tunnels.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a static ip address add on to ensure your app connected via that ip address.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguardstatic

But I don't know how that gets you to a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

If your company have Heroku Enterprise, looks like it could be done within Private Space:
[https://blog.heroku.com/heroku_private_spaces_are_now_generally_available_within_heroku_enterprise]

[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces]

Otherwise the easiest way I could think of is to spin up an proxy server in your DMZ that is restricted access from your Heroku app... with setting static IP suggestion above from mooreds.