# VPN on EC2 to Heroku server

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, heroku, amazon-ec2, ssh

Hi there networking experts,

I have a Rails app hosted on Heroku, and I am looking to set up a VPN tunnel on a separate EC2 instance which will connect with a 3rd party.

> 3rd party <----(VPN tunnel)----> EC2 <----(HTTP/SSH)---> Heroku

Best case scenario would have been to set up the tunnel directly on our Heroku instance, but that doesn't seem possible according to some of these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314057/connecting-to-server-behind-vpn-with-heroku-and-ruby).

With my limited knowledge, I figured that the next best thing would be to set up a 'middle-man' EC2 instance with the capability to listen to the VPN tunnel as well as send HTTP requests to our Heroku server over SSH. The most important consideration in this integration would be security. I would like to encrypt end-to-end, and only decrypt on our Heroku server.

What would be the best practice for achieving something like this, if possible at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a managed VPN offering.

You configure a customer gateway for the client side, attach a virtual private gateway to your VPC, and the VPN connects the two.  You can then set up routes which will allow them to connect securely to any services running inside your VPC.

A VPN in AWS can use static or dynamic routing.  Static is generally simpler, especially if there is a limited IP range on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Chris.
I am a novice when it comes to server infrastructure.. Would you recommend storing the received data on an Amazon RDS, or route it directly over to our Heroku server where we currently have our Postgresql server? 
Either way, I would need direct, encrypted transfer to and from EC2 to Heroku, which I do not know if it is possible.